# Why does a relocation table contain only relative addresses?

Tags: assembly, mips, symbols, relocation

I'm learning about Assemblers for a class, and I'm struggling to find a clear explanation of why relocation tables contain only a relative address.  Why does the relocation table need relative addresses?  Could it theoretically point to absolute addresses?

Thanks!

Comment: Absolute addresses by their very nature don't change, and don't need to be relocated. So, why would you need an entry for them? What do you want to do with them?

Comment: @Jester Referencing what Wikipedia is telling me, if "each entry in the table... is a pointer to an absolute address in the object code that must be changed when the loader relocates the program so that it will refer to the correct location," could absolute addresses just be stored and changed or determined at run-time?  Or is a relative address just this pointer to an absolute address?  Thanks, and sorry if this is an odd question.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are asking about. If  you write an absolute address yourself, then you expect that address to be unchanged. E.g. if you know a device is at address `foo` you want that to stay the same no matter where your program is relocated to. However, if you just reference something that will be relocated by a symbol and the generated instruction happens to use an absolute address, you will need a relocation entry. So in that sense, yes, you could have relocation entry for an absolute address. Did that help any? :)

Comment: PECOFF and ELF both support "absolute" relocations (IMAGE_REL_xxx_ABSOLUTE and R_xxx_NONE types respectively), but as Jester's comment suggests relocations of these types don't do anything. They're ignored by the linker.

Comment: @Jester it did, thank you!

Comment: @Ross Ridge this is also informative - thanks!